# Why need React this code, that my code works?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend

This is my code

```
const Input = props => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>{props.label}</label>
      <input 
        className="input" 
        type={props.type} 
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
      ></input>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

I want to receive data from an other component from my app. But it only works with a other line of code after the first props call:

```
    const Input = (props: { label: boolean | React.ReactChild | React.ReactFragment | React.ReactPortal | null | undefined; type: string | (string & {}) | undefined; placeholder: string | undefined; }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>{props.label}</label>
      <input 
        className="input" 
        type={props.type} 
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
      ></input>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Is there a way to make this code look more beautiful?

Thank you!

Comment: this question is best asked here : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: how are you passing the props to the component?

Comment: Passing the props like this: <Component label="label prop" type="url prop" placeholder="placeholder prop"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your frustrated on the looks of the part where you have to declare the types of the input field.

> ```
> const Input = (props: { label: boolean | React.ReactChild | React.ReactFragment | React.ReactPortal | null | undefined; type: string | (string & {}) | undefined; placeholder: string | undefined; }) => {
> ```

What I would do If I was you is above your functional component is create a new Typescript Type called `InputProps` and set it to that so your new code would look like:

```
// new stuff here
type InputProps = {
  label: boolean | React.ReactChild | React.ReactFragment | React.ReactPortal | null | undefined;
  type: type: string | (string & {}) | undefined;
  placeholder: string | undefined;
}

    const Input = (props: InputProps) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>{props.label}</label>
      <input 
        className="input" 
        type={props.type} 
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
      ></input>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

This would be the best way to tidy up this code by not having the type definitions in your function, but as a separate type object.

Comment: Thank you! Nice idea, i will use it. But i mean is there no way to make this without the type definitions?

Comment: No, if you want to have your functional component to have typing this is the best you can get. Unfortunately that is the one downside to having typed components is writing your types can be a little messy...

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I couldn't offer a cleaner solution.

Comment: You can make it clearer (at least more DRY) by picking already defined attributes of HTMLInputElement `type InputProps = { label?: ReactChild } & Partial<Pick<HTMLInputElement, 'type'|'placeholder'>>`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko you should add that as an answer. I didn't think about that.